# Find a closed formula (not including $\sum$) for the expression $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

Find a closed formula (not including $\sum$) for the expression
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}$$
I started by using the fact that
$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
to get that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2k+1}+\binom{2n-1}{2k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-2}{2k+1}+\binom{2n-2}{2k}+\binom{2n-2}{2k}+\binom{2n-2}{2k-1}$$
now letting $m=n-1$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m+2}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2k+1}+2\cdot\binom{2m}{2k}+\binom{2m}{2k-1}$$
I'm not exactly sure where to go from here or even if this has been helpful. Any guidance/alternative methods would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Applying binomial theorem on $(1+1)^{2n}$ and $(1-1)^{2n}$ could be useful.

Comment: Depending on what you already know, it could also be helpful to note that the sum is the number of odd-sized subsets of a set of $2n$ things.

Comment: Spoiler alert: the case $n=0$ is special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k=(1+1)^{2n}=2^{2n}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2n}k=(1-1)^{2n}=[n=0]$$
Thus, subtracting the second sum from the first cancels all even indices and leaves only twice the odd indices:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}=\frac{2^{2n}-[n=0]}2=2^{2n-1}[n>0]$$

Comment: Typo in first line: It should be $(1+1)^{2n}$

Comment: The $0$ in the second line should instead be $[n=0]$ because $0^0=1$.

Comment: And then also in the final result.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\sum_{k\ge0} a_{2k+1} = \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}a_k.$$
Taking $$a_k=\binom{2n}{k}$$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{2n}{2k+1} 
&= \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{1-(-1)^k}{2} \binom{2n}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{2n}{k} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge0} (-1)^k\binom{2n}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1+1)^{2n} - \frac{1}{2}(1-1)^{2n} \\
&= \frac{4^n-[n=0]}{2}.
\end{align}